# Cleaning up columns to look less messy in a ggplot in R-studio

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a dataset containing information on a species of spider, where I have 3 different life stages.
There are different days data has been collected throughout a total of 2 years, for two different study sites.
I am working on a graph in r using ggplot2, but my columns are looking really messy; they are overlapping at some points and not showing all the information in others.

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could make my graph look cleaner and more presentable?
I want to make sure I can see all the columns for each life stage for each date.
I am quite new to r, and programming in general, so it might be that the solution is very simple and I just haven't found it yet.

As stated, i am using ggplot to make my graph.

I have tried to correct some of the weirdness by increasing the width of the columns, but that only makes them overlap, and I have also tried different intervals of showing the dates, but if I have individual dates it looks too messy and it is not possible to read them all.

Here is a subset of my data if anyone wants to try it out:

```
    Date       Place        Llifestages  Count
   <date>     <chr>        <chr>        <int>
 1 2021-09-15 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       0
 2 2021-09-15 Nedre Leberg total_medium     0
 3 2021-09-15 Nedre Leberg total_large      2
 4 2021-09-15 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       0
 5 2021-09-15 Nedre Leberg total_medium     0
 6 2021-09-15 Nedre Leberg total_large      2
 7 2021-09-15 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       0
 8 2021-09-15 Nedre Leberg total_medium     0
 9 2021-09-15 Nedre Leberg total_large      7
10 2021-09-15 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       0
11 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_medium     2
12 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_large      0
13 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       0
14 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_medium     2
15 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_large      6
16 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       0
17 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_medium     2
18 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_large      2
19 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       0
20 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_medium     0
21 2022-04-23 Nedre Leberg total_large      2
22 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_large      0
23 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       1
24 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_medium     0
25 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_large      0
26 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       1
27 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_medium     0
28 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_large      0
29 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       0
30 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_medium     1
31 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_large      0
32 2022-07-04 Nedre Leberg total_tiny       0
```

I have made it so that the dates act as actual dates in my file:

`#date to usable date: data_long$Date <- as.Date(data_long$Date)`

And this is how my ggplot code looks like:

```
#life stages graph
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = Date, y = Count, fill = Llifestages))+
  labs(title = "Spider life stages",
       x = "Date", y = "Amount of spiders")+
  scale_fill_grey(start=0.8, end=0.2)  +
  facet_wrap(~ Place, ncol = 2)+
 theme_bw()+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 20)
```

Which makes this graph:

[graph showing life stages, with messy columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKsnD.jpg)

And when I am not making the columns thicker I can barely see any of the columns at all:

[even messier columns that are so thin you can't see them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtG3e.jpg)

Feel free to ask if I need to give more context or coding, I am new to this site :-)
Added a small subset of my data.

Comment: Maybe try to use `geom_line` instead so that the three life stages are shown by lines connecting consecutive time points? `geom_line(aes(group = lifestages))`

Comment: I would, but my supervisors specifically want me to use columns, not lines

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.